# How do I calculate participation rate with survey_weight?

Tags: sas, survey

I have a data file containing survey responses. These respondents are folks in my county who were invited to participate in a local festival. The variables are respondent_id, zip_code, survey_weight, and participated. Participated is binary. 1 indicates that they participated in the festival, and 0 indicates that they didn't.

I need to calculate the participation rate with the given survey_weight BY respondent_id.

I tried several procedures including surveymeans and means.

This is what I did.

```
proc surveymeans data=survey_data sum mean;
  strata zip_code;
  weight survey_weight;
  var participated;
  domain zip_code;
run;
```

Also this.

```
proc means data=survey_data sum;
  class zip_code;
  var participated survey_weight;
  weight survey_weight;
  output out=zip_summary sum(participated)=total_part sum(survey_weight)=total_survey_weights;
```

run;

```
data zip_summary;
  set zip_summary;
  participation_rate = total_part / total_survey_weights;
run;


proc print data=zip_summary;
  var zip participation_rate;
run;
```

Although they run, I don't know if the number is right.

Comment: You can convince yourself that you have written the SAS statements to create the results you want by mocking up some simple data and seeing if the SAS results are the same as your hand-computed results.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the `PROC FREQ` procedure, however I am not too strong in that facility. Another option is to do it using `PROC SQL`.

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE zip_summary AS
    SELECT 
        zip_code,
        survey_weight,

        MEAN(participated) AS participated FORMAT PERCENT20.2
    FROM
        survey_data
    GROUP BY
        zip_code,
        survey_weight
    ;
QUIT;
```

Sample data:

```
DATA survey_data;
    CALL STREAMINIT(1);
    DO zip_code = 900, 1000, 1200, 1300;
        DO survey_weight = 1 TO 2;
            DO respondent_id = 1 TO 1e3;
                participated = RAND("Bernoulli", 0.5);
                OUTPUT;
            END;
        END;
    END;
RUN;
/*
zip_code    weight     participated                           
-----------------------------------                           
     900         1           51.70%                            
     900         2           47.00%                            
    1000         1           49.30%                            
    1000         2           49.60%                            
    1200         1           51.10%                            
    1200         2           48.70%                            
    1300         1           50.70%                            
    1300         2           50.20%  
*/
```